# Recipient List does not match Sent to List in Sent Sitecore EXM Campaign

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-exm

I've recently sent out an EXM Campaign message to a recipient list of 461 Recipients, however the Sent to number displays 300.  Is there a way for me to see which recipients did not get an email, or more importantly, why the message was only sent to 300 of the 461 contacts?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Content Editor in [FF or IE or Safari](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/604276)
2. Find engagement plan that correspond your ExM Campaign. It is located
   */sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Engagement Plans/Email
   Campaign/Emails/[YEAR]/[MONTH]/[DAYandTIMESTAMP]/[NAMEofYOURCAMPAIGN]*
3. Click "Monitor" button

You will be able to see amount of recipients in each state and will be able to figure out who received email and who not.

Comment: Thanks! That helps, but opens up more questions.  The Email Campaign engagement plan mentioned 330 as the number of contacts, not 461 as stated in the list of sent email in EXM.

Comment: Was list indexing finished before sending email? Do all contacts haver email addresses?

Comment: All contacts have email address.  BUT I'm not sure if the list indexing finished before sending the email.  I'm not sure if there is a way to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can see the reports by do the below steps.

1. Open Email Experience Manager
2. In the  Dash Board left section under the report click the on the "Sent"
3. Click the Sent Message Dash board, click on the message you want to see the report.
4. In the Report Screen, it will show you the all the details like, Total recipients, Active recipients, Unsubscribers and Email Bounces.